i2c baudrate stored but not applied
I am having a bad time trying to set the baudrate of the i2c bus 0...
Setup:

RaspberryPi 3b with a buildroot Linux image.
we communicate with our home-made bare-metal chips over i2c.
after every change in config.txt I do a reboot
I check the I2C baudrate using a scope on SCL while doing i2cdetect -y $bus in a while loop
pins used from https://pinout.xyz/pinout/i2c

In my setup, we use both i2c bus i2c_arm and i2c_vc.
To have this working, I changed my config.txt to add
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=i2c_vc=on

and it works as expected.
(Please do not tell me I should not use i2c_vc, I read a lot of pages already. But up to here, it works.)
The data I want to send over I2C are large and I want to speed things up. So I try to configure the baudrate. I edit again my config.txt and change it to
dtparam=i2c_arm=on,i2c_arm_baudrate=400000
dtparam=i2c_vc=on,i2c_vc_baudrate=400000

as specified in https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/48cd9f9dfe536c5ad32367a1554b12d5a7325d00/boot/overlays/README#L313
Now troubles start.
It works as expected on the regular I2C bus 1 (ARM) but it has no effect on the other bus 0 (VC).
I measure the SCL on a scope and on bus 0 while looping i2cdetect -y 0 commands and it is still the default 100kHz.
I also tried to set it to a lower value 50000 thinking maybe 100kHz was its max but again it has no effect.
Since they are actually aliases I tried the real names
https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#part3.3 and I also tried changing the order of the lines in config.txt, for instance writing
dtparam=i2c0_baudrate=50000
dtparam=i2c0=on,i2c0_baudrate=50000
dtparam=i2c1=on,i2c1_baudrate=400000

but again with no effect.
What is more troubling is that when I read the value in
/sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-0/device/of_node/clock_frequency
I always read the exact value I set in my config.txt (after the reboot)...
Interesting fact:
# i2cdetect -l
i2c-0   i2c         i2c-11-mux (chan_id 0)              I2C adapter
i2c-1   i2c         bcm2835 (i2c@7e804000)              I2C adapter
i2c-10  i2c         i2c-11-mux (chan_id 1)              I2C adapter
i2c-11  i2c         bcm2835 (i2c@7e205000)              I2C adapter

so I am not sure what happens, if there is some GPIO bitbang in the background for bus 0...
This setup is using a buildroot image with busybox. RootFS is read-only squashFS but I don't think this plays a role. If it helps I can provide parts of the .config file. We only have the root user. We have other RPi with the same image using the camera so the .config contains
BR2_PACKAGE_RPI_FIRMWARE=y
BR2_PACKAGE_RPI_FIRMWARE_VARIANT_PI_X=y
BR2_PACKAGE_RPI_FIRMWARE_INSTALL_DTB_OVERLAYS=y
BR2_PACKAGE_RPI_USERLAND=y

When we boot, there is in /etc/init.d script to execute
modprobe i2c-dev
modprobe i2c-bcm2708

I also tried during runtime to do
modprobe -r i2c-dev
modprobe i2c-dev baudrate=400000
modprobe -r i2c-bcm2708
modprobe i2c-bcm2708 baudrate=400000

with no effect.
I checked also lsmod and I get
Module                  Size  Used by    Tainted: G  
i2c_bcm2708            16384  0 
i2c_dev                20480  0
[...]
i2c_mux_pinctrl        16384  0 
i2c_mux                16384  1 i2c_mux_pinctrl
i2c_bcm2835            16384  0
[...]

but not sure what to do of this...
As I started doubting about everything, I unplugged everything from the RPi but still got the same results so it doesn't seem to be related to my connected HW.
So...
Now I am getting out of hairs to pull... I don't know how it can keep the default value while at the same time telling me it has my configured value...
I am kind of stuck and I don't know if I should check deeper in the Linux kernel, in the RaspberryPi FW, some odd i2c pull-ups somewhere, or if there is something in my boot process altering this value...
Any hint welcome...
EDIT: I also tried to have ChatGPT help me with this and did several other explorations. Here is the thread: https://chatgpt.com/share/66f3b45e-3d84-8001-8158-2f9fdb447eac

I have successfully used dtparam=i2c_baudrate=400000 (which I believe is max supported)
You appear to have invented parameters NOT in standard DT  i2c0_baudrate, i2c1_baudrate
You CAN use i2c_arm_baudrate BUT the documentation says:-
i2c_baudrate            An alias for i2c_arm_baudrate

_
i2c_vc                  Set to "on" to enable the i2c interface
                                usually reserved for the VideoCore processor
                                (default "off")

If you choose to use the reserved interface (which is connected to a multiplexer) presumably set in the firmware you wouldn't be able to change.

i2c_arm_baudrate or its alias i2c_baudrate (which are in fact aliases of i2c1_baudrate) works like a charm, my trouble is with i2c_vc_baudrate. Actually I tried first the official parameters (like i2c_vc_baudrate https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/48cd9f9dfe536c5ad32367a1554b12d5a7325d00/boot/overlays/README#L313 ) but I also saw some documentation saying those were just aliases so I tried the real names https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#part3.3 I will edit my post to add this information.
